# TinyMCE absorb my event

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, tinymce

When the tinyMCE is active and I click my save button then it prevent or absorb that click event.

I tried override blur but it was no effect:

```
tinymce.init({
...
setup: function(editor) {
            editor.on('blur', function(e) {
                e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                e.preventDefault();
                return false;
            });
    }, ...
```

and i was searching any solution a lot but no result.

Please help me!

Thanks!

Comment: can you create a tinymce fiddle for this?

Comment: There?: http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: that doesn't work - there isn't a valid fiddle

Comment: Ok i know what is the problem, but i dont know what will be the solutin. So, when i click outside of editor then it try set to focus to next element. So i think i should prevent this feature but how to? (Because the Firefox jump to input what is just focused.)

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna try this:

```
setup: function(editor) {
         editor.on('init', function(e) {
            $(editor.getBody()).on('blur', function(e) {
                e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                e.preventDefault();
                return false;
            });
        });
    }, ...
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not working. But I am getting close to solving the issue. I figured out that when I click on the form, it is being reset by TinyMCE. I tried to remove this feature but I couldn't do it. Can you help me?